# Sort array of duplicate integers in place

Tags: sorting, arrays

Given an array of integers within [1, n] where n = size of array, some elements may appear more than once.

Could we sort it with just 1 extra space and in O(n) time?

Comment: You might be able to implement counting sort in-place, depending on the exact computation model. For example, this is the case if you can store at each cell an integer up to $n^2$.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to specify the computational model and any assumptions or restrictions on the algorithms we're allowed to use.  The answer may depend on delicate details about the theoretical model of computation you are using to analyze the algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Use Radix sort. The time complexity is O(kn) and space complexity is O(k + n) . Here n is the number of elements and k is the number of bits required to represent largest element in the array.

Comment: Since the largest element in the array could be $n$, and $k\sim \log n$, wouldn't this be $O(n \log n)$?

Comment: @user111398 But, isn't $O(nlogn)$ better than $O(n^2)$?

Comment: @user111398 I listed the worst case time and space complexity of Radix sort. So, if you can prove it to be O(nlogn) that would be a scientific accomplishment. But radix sort and counting sort are the only linear time worst case algorithms. And question was to solve it in linear time with no more than 1 extra space complexity. so this is as close as it get(in worst case scenario).